# How replace li on ul with replaceChild

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code on a webpage:

```
<ul id="liste">
    <li>Paris</li>
    <li>Marseille</li>
    <li>Lyon</li>
    <li>Strasbourg</li>
    <li>Bordeaux</li>
    <li>Toulouse</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to replace the third item of `<li>` by a name I will type in this

```
<input type="button" value="onclick="remplacer_ville()"/><input id="remplacement" type="text"/><br /><br />
```

I try this function but it doesn't work. Help!

```
function remplacer_ville(){

        var ul = document.getElementById('liste');
        var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

        var troisieme_ville = li[2];
        var nouvelle_ville = document.getElementById('remplacement').value;
        troisieme_ville.replaceChild(nouvelle_ville,troisieme_ville);

}
```

i'm sorry my english is bad i'm french

Comment: By "thirst", do you mean first or third ?

Comment: As a sidenote, element.value returns a string, you can't replace a string with methods that work on DOM nodes ?

Comment: `value="onclick="remplacer_ville()"/>` will not work anyway, correct: `value="Replace" onclick="remplacer_ville()" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to get the value that was typed by the user and put it into the 2nd `<li>` tag, then you need to go about it differently:

```
    var ul = document.getElementById('liste');
    var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    var troisieme_ville = li[2];
    var nouvelle_ville = document.getElementById('remplacement').value;

    // now put this value into the li tag by setting the .innerHTML
    troisieme_ville.innerHTML = nouvelle_ville;
```

`.replaceChild()` tries to take one DOM element and replace it with another and takes a DOM element as its argument.  That doesn't appear to be what you want to do at all here.  It looks like what you want to do is take the value typed in the input field and put it into the `<li>` tag which you can do be setting the `.innerHTML` property.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes that's what I wanted to do and it works,

Answer (score 0):

See this is what you have to do

check this:  http://jsfiddle.net/Pxhgw/

```
<html>
<script>
function remplacer_ville(){
 var ul = document.getElementById('liste');
    var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
var troisieme_ville = li[2];
var nouvelle_ville = document.getElementById('remplacement').value;
troisieme_ville.innerHTML = nouvelle_ville;
}
</script>
<body>
<ul id="liste">
<li>Paris</li>
<li>Marseille</li>
<li id="k">Lyon</li>
<li>Strasbourg</li>
<li>Bordeaux</li>
<li>Toulouse</li></ul>
<input type="button" value="onclick="remplacer_ville()"/><input 

 id="remplacement" type="text" onchange="remplacer_ville()"/><br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much ;) and i didn't know your link, i will use it thank you, it look like more better than use an software

Comment: pleasure is all mine  :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [fiddle answer](http://jsfiddle.net/csrow/Yj7Jc/1/)

```
<ul id="liste">
    <li>Paris</li>
    <li>Marseille</li>
    <li>Lyon</li>
    <li>Strasbourg</li>
    <li>Bordeaux</li>
    <li>Toulouse</li>
</ul>

<input type="button" value="Change" onclick="remplacer_ville()" />
<input id="remplacement" type="text"/><br /><br />
```

with the function...

```
function remplacer_ville(){

        var ula = document.getElementById('liste');
        var lia = ula.getElementsByTagName('li');

        var troisieme_ville = lia[2];
        var nouvelle_ville = 
            document.getElementById('remplacement').value;
        troisieme_ville.innerHTML=nouvelle_ville;

};
```